# Is there a way to make jQuery Tiny Scrollbar have 100% height in relation to screen size?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scrollbar, fullscreen

I am banging my head against the wall. I have a full screen design that I am working on. Searched high and low to try and find a way to make [Tiny Scrollbar](http://www.baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/) work with [this design](http://truered.com/ar_web). I have a side panel slider working just fine and I want the scroller to fill the the vertical right side of the screen. I have the scroller in there as well. I currently have the "viewport" set to height:600px;, if I set the height to 100% or use a min height all content inside the scroller disappears. I want the scroller to resize with the screen size.

Any suggestions would make my year!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ultimately lead client in a different direction.

Answer (score 3):

if you still need it:

```
var heightscroll = $(window).height();  
         $('.viewport').css('height', heightscroll );
```

Works for me , but is needed a function to update the height when window is resized.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do the above with .viewport resize when browser window is resized with this code:

```
$(function() {  

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var heightscroll = $(window).height();
        $('.viewport').css('height', heightscroll); 
    });

    $(window).resize();
});
```

I have no idea how to resize the scrollbar handle properly, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it:

```
$(function() {  
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var heightscroll = $(window).height();
        $('.viewport').css('height', heightscroll-48);              
        var oScrollbar = $('#scrollbar');
        oScrollbar.tinyscrollbar();
        oScrollbar.tinyscrollbar_update();
    });
    $(window).resize();
});
```

Note: I used heightscroll-48 because I have a header I want fixed above the scroll. If you really want full 100% height just use heightscroll and delete "-48".